# Array.prototype.forEach.call gives TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, call, typeerror

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

`Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.body.children, console.log);`

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation(…)(anonymous function)

Which seems like nonsense as the following both work:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.body.children, function () {console.log(arguments)});
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.body.children, l=>console.log(l));
```

> NOTE: the function being called (`console.log` in this case) is just an example, the original intent was to use `document.body.removeChild` instead, but this failed in the same way.
>
> ANOTHER NOTE: I've only tried this in Chrome. I tried the following in a *node.js* console and it worked fine:

`Array.prototype.forEach.call(myArray, console.log)`

Comment: `console.log.bind(console)`, `document.body.removeChild.bind(document.body)`

Comment: Ah so I need to bind `document.body` (or the DOM element) I'm calling `removeChild` on - thanks @SergeSeredenko

Answer (score 4):

That's because the `console.log` method must be called on the `console` object:

```
var log = console.log;
log(123); /* TypeError: 'log' called on an object that
             does not implement interface Console. */
log.call(console, 123); /* Works */
```

You can fix by passing a third argument to `forEach`, which determines the `this` value:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.body.children, console.log, console);
```

Or you can bind `console.log` to `console`:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.body.children, console.log.bind(console));
```

There is also a proposal of a [bind operator](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:bind_operator):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.body.children, ::console.log);
```